# Send 2 messages to 1 channel using .then()

Tags: discord.js

Hi i wanted to send 2 messages to 1 channelusing then because ive been using this:
`` message.guild.channels.create(`ticket ${message.author.username}`, { type: 'text', permissionOverwrites: [ { id: message.guild.id, deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], }, { id: message.author.id, allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], }, { type: 'role', id: '699008330311663775', allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], }, ], }).then(channel => channel.send(`${message.author} ${embed}`)); ``

But it doesnt send the ping and the embed. Its sends "(Ping) [Object] [Object]" in the channel. `channel.send(message.author + embed)`also doesnt work and using `.then()` after already using it doesnt work too, but i want to send a ping and the mebed. Can someone pls help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `embed` is a `MessageEmbed`, you have can't send it in a string or it will simply convert to `[object Object]`. If you want to send an embed with text, simply put the embed in the second parameter.

```js
channel.send(message.author.toString(), { embed });
```

Comment: omg thanks ive been looking for this so long